# Trying to deploy shiny app with a google drive connection

Tags: r, shiny, google-drive-api, shinyapps

My code uses a file located in the g-drive and I am having issues deploying the R-Shiny app to shinyapps.io because of this connection

The script works locally but I get the following error when I try to deploy:

"Error: Can't get google credentials
Are you runing googledrive in a non-interactive session? Consider:
drive_deauth() or drive_auth()..."

Drive deauth gives me a 403 error regarding credentials to my own g-drive and the drive_auth() are giving me the similar error above, even when i pass all the different arguments in the documentation

my latest atempt

```
drive_auth_config(active = FALSE)

drive_find()
drive_download(
  "CST_Tree.csv",
  path = "..\\Shiny\\CST_Tree.csv",
  overwrite = TRUE
)

df <- read.csv("CST_Tree.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

See my thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051305/struggling-to-use-my-own-api-key-with-googlesheets4-in-shinyapps-io).

I struggled for a while to get it working as I didn't (and still don't!) understand OAuth tokens.

My understanding of the GoogleDrive and GoogleSheets packages are that they come "pre-configured" with a "public" token and kind of work "out-of-the-box", but you may run into problems with API limitations, since there are lots of people using it.

I found it best to set up my own Google API Account and use that to authorise the use of GoogleDrive and GoogleSheets in my Shiny App.

It's not terribly straightforward, but hopefully my thread link helps?

Answer (score 2):

First set authorities for google drive (this should go in your app.R):

```
options(
  # whenever there is one account token found, use the cached token
  gargle_oauth_email = TRUE,
  # specify auth tokens should be stored in a hidden directory ".secrets"
  gargle_oauth_cache = "Your project folder name/.secrets"
)
```

Then outside your app.R, be sure you store the tokens for google drive and google sheets:

```
googledrive::drive_auth()
googlesheets4::gs4_auth()
```

For more instruction try:
https://www.jdtrat.com/blog/connect-shiny-google/